# Update Table With Join Condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I have following scenario.

```
 Table A // Dev
 ID
 NAME
 Address

 Table A  // Prod
 ID
 NAME
 Address
```

While Deleting from Dev i need to check if it exists in prod and if it does then i need to restore it's values from prod and delete all those don't exist in Prod. ANY SQL help around this? Can anyone suggest a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Lookup

[image]

1.Source will be your development .

2.Drag a lookup and write a query to get the ID from the production table .Match the ID's from source and Production in Lookup and select the ID from Production as well as other columns in production

[image]

3.Drag a OLedb command and write a query to update the dev

```
 update d set d.Col1 = ?, d.Col2 =?
  from dev.tableA d 
  where d.id = ?
```

4.Similary write the query for delete and map the columns selected fromn the lookup

```
  delete from dev.tableA
  where id <> ?
```

Note: Oleb command executes for each row .Therefore it will be slow if you have too many rows . If performance is a main concern then you can dump all the data after lookup into a table in your development server and then use [Merge](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/the-merge-statement-in-sql-server-2008/) syntax in a  Execute SQL task to perform update and delete operation

Answer (score 1):

If both databases are in the same instance then you could try following queries:

```
--update query
update d set d.name = p.name, d.address = p.address
from dev.dbo.tableA d 
        join prod.dbo.tableA p on d.id = p.id

--delete query
delete dev.dbo.tableA
where id not in (select id from prod.dbo.tableA)
```

Comment: Thanks, Can you please suggest if both are on different Servers how SSIS can handle this job

Comment: I am not an expert on SSIS but if you use `Data Import and Export Wizard` you should be able to select the database servers and then select `Write a query to specify the data to transfer` option. At the end of it you should be able to save it as an SSIS package.